# Get the count of HTTP threads on glassfish

Tags: java, multithreading, glassfish-3, grizzly

I have created a dedicated thread pool to handle specific HTTP requests in Glassfish v3. I would like to get the number of inactive threads (free- not running) at any given point of time as I need to throttle the HTTP requests depending on the availability of worker threads. Is there a exposed API to get this? I don't want to submit the request to the thread pool unless threads are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To answer your question:**  As per best of my knowledge there is so no such API which can give you handy details you require, so I think you have to compute it yourself.

**For solution part:**   `java.lang.management` package should help you.

***java.lang.management.ManagementFactory***
The ManagementFactory class is a factory class for getting managed beans for the Java platform.
You can consider using `ManagementFactory` which lets you get details from the JVM through exposed Java managed beans. For your case, you can use `ThreadMXBean` which will let you get all JVM thread information.

***java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean***
The management interface for the thread system of the Java virtual machine.
Read `ThreadMXBean`  documentation and API thoroughly to understand it well, and I think in the end you can use `java.lang.management.ThreadInfo` object to get all the info you need.

***java.lang.management.ThreadInfo***
`java.lang.management.ThreadInfo` gets you a lot of Thread details as listed below. I don't think any other Java class can give this much info about Thread.

- Thread ID.
- Name of the thread.
- Thread state.
- The object upon which the thread is blocked due to:

  - waiting to enter a synchronization block/method, or
  - waiting to be notified in a Object.wait method, or
  - parking due to a LockSupport.park call.
- The ID of the thread that owns the object that the thread is blocked.
- Stack trace of the thread.
- List of object monitors locked by the thread.
- List of ownable synchronizers locked by the thread.

Below is a sample I have created for you, please note this is to get you started and a full-fledged solution cannot be provided, so please do more research about it, but I think would be helpful.
I am getting all thread states and printing them, so you can do IF-ELSE and then prepare a list of something based on state etc. and then take necessary action.

Hope this helps!

```
private static void getThreadInfo() {
    System.out.println("Started");
    ThreadMXBean managementFactory = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
    long threadIds[] = managementFactory.getAllThreadIds();
    for (int i = 0; i < threadIds.length; i++) {
        ThreadInfo info = managementFactory.getThreadInfo(threadIds[i]);
        System.out.println("Thread name = " + info.getThreadName() + " Thread id = " + info.getThreadId() + " Thread state = " + info.getThreadState());
    }

    System.out.println("#############");
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getAllStackTraces());
}
```

Output:

```
Started
Thread name = Attach Listener Thread id = 5 Thread state = RUNNABLE
Thread name = Signal Dispatcher Thread id = 4 Thread state = RUNNABLE
Thread name = Finalizer Thread id = 3 Thread state = WAITING
Thread name = Reference Handler Thread id = 2 Thread state = WAITING
Thread name = main Thread id = 1 Thread state = RUNNABLE
#############
{Thread[Finalizer,8,system]=[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@1748ba4, Thread[Attach Listener,5,system]=[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@7bd86d, Thread[main,5,main]=[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@bdff3b, Thread[Reference Handler,10,system]=[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@1bf8a41, Thread[Signal Dispatcher,9,system]=[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@dd841}
```